# Can't build after angular migration from 5 to 6 - Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: angular, migration

I'm migrating angular application from 5 to 6. Run

`ng update @angular/cli`and `ng update @angular/core`

But now if i run `ng build`, i get this error

```
Cannot find module 'typescript' from 'C:\..\App'
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript' from 'C:\..\App'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:42:15)
    at resolveProjectModule (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\utilities\require-project-module.js:15:20)
    at Object.requireProjectModule (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\utilities\require-project-module.js:20:20)
    at BrowserBuilder.buildWebpackConfig (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:103:52)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:35:38)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
    at C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at TapSubscriber._next (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\..\App\MyApp\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
```

package.json includes`"typescript": ">=2.7.0 <2.8.0"` in devDependencies

Cleaned npm cache and reinstalled all packages but it didn't help.

Anybody with same issues?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611526/how-to-fix-cannot-find-module-typescript-in-angular-4

Comment: seems not to be the same .angular-cli.json is not needed anymore. Reinstall didn't help

Comment: Did you follow all steps in https://update.angular.io ?

Comment: yes. Last step - rxjs migration seems not to affect this issue. But i'm not sure

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you fix by any chance?

Comment: @developer i dont know exactly what i did, but it works now. Maybe some package wasn't installed correctly (i had some issues with corporate proxy). Project typescript version is 2.7.2

Comment: Thanks Juri, it worked for me after installing typescript cleanly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reinstall typescript cleanly

```
- npm uninstall -g typescript
- npm uninstall typescript
- npm install -g typescript
- npm install typescript@2.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent way too much time for this. Due to specific folder structure the problem was with `root` path inside `angular.json`. It pointed to `..` which was 'outside' of the project instead of root folder.