# Cannot find Typescript using NVM

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nvm

I  have nvm installed and recently fixed an issue with a conflict with a previously installed version of node.  Fixing it meant removing the node executable from the prior location.  Some things still work but I'm getting this error: 
`Cannot find module 'typescript'`

and this fix didn't help me:
[How to fix Cannot find module 'typescript' in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611526/how-to-fix-cannot-find-module-typescript-in-angular-4)

running ng new is what is triggering the error.

I have typescript installed globally. And to ensure that is installed with this version of node, I ran:

```
nvm use 10 && npm i -g typescript
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
```

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: Do you have typescript installed globally? If yes, try to execute npm i,  before you run ng new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this question, I found the answer here.
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

I had to do all of the steps in the most accepted answer. I also had to:

```
rm -Rf /user/local/bin/node_modules
```

It might be a good idea to search your machine for all node_modules folders and, of course, ignore any "local" versions.  And delete all of them that are not in your nvm directory.  That directory will look somehting like:

```
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v#####/lib/node_modules
```

You can identify yours using:

```
npm root -g
```

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will help folks ...

You can use `mv,` to install `Typescript`; this seems good for me, but I don't go our of my way to use Typescript.

```
$ nvm  --version
$ nvm  use stable
$ npm  install typescript --save-dev
$ npx  tsc --version
Version 5.0.4
$
```

what seems to work is fine for me :-)

See also:

- [Typescript download](https://www.typescriptlang.org/download)

Answer (score 1):

When using nvm, every node version has it's own globally installed dependencies. If you are not finding something you have installed previously for a different version of node (or you have removed it), this can be a reason.