# Command not found: ts-node-dev

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node-dev

I am moving from `nodemon` to `ts-node-dev` but I am not able to run my `index.ts` file using `ts-node-dev`.

I did the following:

1. `yarn add ts-node-dev --dev`
2. In my `package.json` I have:

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
      ...
      "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
      "ts-node": "8.3.0",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.56",
      "typescript": "3.6.3"
   }
   ```

If I run `ts-node-dev` or `ts-node-dev src/index.ts` I get the error:
**command not found: ts-node-dev**

What am I doing wrong? It seems to me that is correctly installed.

**My scripts**

```
   "scripts": {
      "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
      "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts"
   }
```

Comment: Is it installed globally?

Comment: I do not think I have to:
https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev
Am I wrong?

Comment: If not, you need to change the working directory to where it's installed, or use a relative/absolute path.

Comment: Credit goes to @DanAbdn from his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611526/how-to-fix-cannot-find-module-typescript-in-angular-4

Specifically,

`npm link typescript` which worked for me

Answer (score 16):

You have 3 options here:

1. Run the command from actual path:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev src/index.ts
```

2. Use `npx`

```sh
npx ts-node-dev src/index.ts
```

3. Install the package globally (wouldn't recommend)

```sh
npm i -g ts-node-dev src/index.ts
ts-node-dev src/index.ts
```

Comment: I tried 1) and 2) and they give me the same issue. It outputs on my terminal `Using ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.6.3` for few seconds, then it exits my terminal

Comment: What does your script look like? What is it supposed to do? Does adding a `console.log` and re-running print anything?

Comment: Add the info to the original question

Comment: If I use option 1 and run: "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./setup-scripts/init-db.ts" it works.  But if I run "npm run db-init" which points to the above line in package.json I get an error.  '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  Any idea why?

Comment: why option.3 is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing my yarn shell script, which I had previously changed to bash.
Returning it to "sh"

```
yarn config set script-shell /bin/sh
```

Or simply reseting it

```
yarn config delete script-shell
```

To check which shell script is being used with

```
yarn config get script-shell
```